# How to select rows that cant pass inner join

Tags: sql-server

I have this query, and there is one problem. How to select all Product rows, those that have category and those that haven't? When Product have category, I will got product with category ,also I will got product with null category. Or if it unreal, how to get all product rows that haven't category.

```
select distinct [dbo].[Category].[CategoryID],[dbo].[Product].[ProductID],[dbo].[Product].[Name],[dbo].[Product].[Description],[dbo].[Product].[Count],
            [dbo].[Product].[Price],[dbo].[Product].[Weight],[dbo].[Product].[Width],[dbo].[Product].[Length],[dbo].[Product].[Height],[BarCode],
            [dbo].[Product].[Image],[dbo].[Product].[Date]  from [dbo].[Product]
            inner join [dbo].[ProductCategory]
            on [dbo].[Product].[ProductID] = [dbo].[ProductCategory].[ProductID]
            inner join [dbo].[Category]
            on [dbo].[ProductCategory].[CategoryID] = [dbo].[Category].[CategoryID]
            order by [dbo].[Product].[ProductID];
```

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Side note: You got to love those `[dbo]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do left join as below and use alias instead of full name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.[CategoryID],
    p.[ProductID],
    p.[NAME],
    p.[Description],
    p.[COUNT],
    p.[Price],
    p.[Weight],
    p.[Width],
    p.[LENGTH],
    p.[Height],
    [BarCode],
    p.[Image],
    p.[DATE]  
FROM [dbo].[Product] p
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ProductCategory] pr ON p.[ProductID] = pr.[ProductID]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Category] ca ON pr.[CategoryID] = ca.[CategoryID]
ORDER BY p.[ProductID];
```